# Modifying the Introduction on the Web API help page

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-helppages

I've enhanced an older SOAP style web service with REST endpoints.  Most everything is working correctly, but I haven't been able to figure out how to change the Introduction on for the auto generated help files.  What I have right now is showing the introduction as "Provide a general description of your APIs here."

I've followed this [Similar question, but doesn't explain where to change Introduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24284413/webapi-help-page-description) and have everything else documented, but still don't know where to change the introduction.

I should be using version 2 of Web-API.

Comment: you can find info [here](http://codethug.com/2015/01/16/web-api-deep-dive-customizing-auto-generated-documentation-part-1-of-6/)

Answer (score 9):

In Visual Studio's Solution Explorer window go to: YourProject -> `Areas` folder -> `HelpPage` -> `Views` -> `Help` -> `index.cshtml` and you will see the text you want to modify.

Alternatively you could just do a find all (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) for the text you are looking for `Provide a general description of your APIs here.`

Once you've modified it, save the `index.cshtml` and refresh the page in your browser. Should be good to go.